# how to detect if your application is pre-installed or not on a machine? (for OEM Preloads)

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows

On a Windows 8.1/10 device, how can i detect if my application is pre-installed on that machine or if it has been installed using the windows store?

Comment: I believe windows store does the check for you?